# Polymorphic property blocks in Obj C as callback functions

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to use a block as a callback function. I store my block as a property in my class that does the calling back:

```
@interface MyParameter
{
    float myValue;
    void (^callback)(float);
}
@property(copy) void (^callback)(float);
@end

@implementation MyParameter
@synthesize callback;

- (void) valueChanged
{
    callback(myValue);
}
@end
```

Then I set the callback:

```
MyParameter * param = [[MyParameter alloc] init];
[param setCallback:^(float value) { [self doSomethingWithValue:value]; }];
```

So far so simple. In reality, `MyParameter`is a generic abstraction which holds details on a runtime-determined number of different types of parameter. I can have continuous (`float`) values, discrete values (`int`) and booleans. So next, I tried this:

```
@interface MyParameter
{
    float floatVal;
    int intVal;
    void (^contCallback)(float);
    void (^discCallback)(int); // And a boolean one too but let's keep this short
    ParamType type; // enum of types ie enum ParamType { Continuous, Discrete, Boolean };
}
@property(copy) void (^contCallback)(float);
@property(copy) void (^discCallback)int);
@end

@implementation MyParameter
@synthesize contCallback;
@synthesize discCallback;

- (void) valueChanged
{   
    switch (type) {
    case Continuous: 
        contCallback(floatVal);
        break;
    case Discrete:
        discCallback(intVal);
        break; 
    // Leave default out for brevity
    }
}
@end
```

Which is getting uglier. I want to keep just one `^callback` as an ivar/property. I then want to set it like this:

```
MyParameter *contParam = [[MyParameter alloc] init];
[contParam setCallback:(^float value) { [self doSomethingContinuous:value]; }];

MyParameter *discreteParam = [[MyParameter alloc] init];
[discreteParam setCallback:(^int value) { [self doSomethingDiscrete:value]; }];
```

Inside `MyParameter` my `valueChanged` method would retain the `switch/case` from above, to decide what to pass in to the callback.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your parameter as an `NSNumber`. You can recover its original type using `-objCType` which will return a string indicating a [type encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1). This way you don't have to polymorph your function call.

Alternately, if `NSNumber` turns out to be too inflexible, just create your own `Argument` data class that encodes whatever information you need. If necessary, you can also create a `Result` data class for the return type.

Comment: Using `NSNumber` worked rather nicely and it seems obvious in retrospect which is a good sign of rightness. Thanks Rob.